# MVC: Iterating a Viewbag array in javascript using the Web Forms view engine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to iterate the contents of a string array, that was put in the ViewBag by the controller, in javascript.

In the controller:

```
ViewBag.Addresses = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

And in the view:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteOnLoad() {

        var array = How do I get "a", "b" and "c" here?;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            doSomething(array[i]);
        }
    }

</script>
```

I searched a lot for an answer but seem to find solutions only for the razor view engine. What about web forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteOnLoad() {

        var array = <%= Html.Raw(ViewBag.Addresses)%>;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                document.write(array[i]);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Then from within your controller:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//serializes array into json

ViewBag.Addresses = js.Serialize(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });
```

Personally I'd look at creating a View model and serializing the array in to a property on the view model and then doing this in your view:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteOnLoad() {

        var array = <%= Html.Raw(Model.Addresses)%>;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                document.write(array[i]);
            }
        }
</script>
```